# Porque este servidor está crashando?

Tags: python, python-3.x, servidor

```
from socket import*


Host = "localhost"
Port = 255

sockobj = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
sockobj.bind((Host, Port))
sockobj.listen(5)

while True:

    conexão, endereço = sockobj.accept()
    print('Server conectado por', endereço)

while True:

    data = conexão.recv(1024)

    if not data:break







        conexão.close()
```

O Python simplesmente trava e não imprime nenhum erro

Comment: Coloca o codigo todo sff. Qual é o erro?

Comment: Esse é o codigo

Comment: Faltam os imports etc... "localhost is not defined", "ame 'AF_INET' is not defined"... etc

Comment: Ele trava... por bug ou porque está esperando eternamente o cliente enviar uma mensagem? Note que o seu programa trata uma conexão por vez, e como ele fica lá parado esperando, pode ser que você só não esteja percebendo que a falha na verdade está no cliente. Note também que os seus laços não está propriamente identados.. Vc tem um `while` infinito só para aceitar conexões! (e, esse, é provavelmente o seu problema: o seu server aceita a primeira conexão, imprime a mensagem "conectado..." e volta a aceitar conexões, ficando "aparentemente" travado)

Comment: Trava sem imprimir erros? será porque o servidor está a funcionar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corrigido, devo começar por dizer que variáveis com caracteres especiais (ç, ã ...) não é de todo aconselhado, e com maiuscula na primeira letra também não é convencional.

Estavas também a fazer dois ciclos `while True:` sem qualquer `break` no primeiro, todos sabemos em que é que isto resulta, quando na verdade é apenas no ultimo (segundo) que precisas que fique "eternamente" a rodar, outra coisa que podes fazer é usar [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html), para "abertura das sockets" desta maneira para além de ser atualmente a mais aconselhada, também escusas de fechar as sockets, tal como o seu uso na abertura de um ficheiro:

```
from socket import*


host = "localhost"
port = 9003

with socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) as sockobj:
    sockobj.bind((host, port))
    sockobj.listen(5)

    conexao, endereco = sockobj.accept() # esperar ate que cliente se ligue
    print('Server conectado por', endereco)

    while True:
        data = conexao.recv(1024)
        if not data:break
```

Nota que quando estive a testar um dos erros que me deu foi:

> ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Isto por causa do `port` que estava a ser utilizado por outro processo qualquer

Comment: "devo começar por dizer que variáveis com caracteres especiais (ç, ã ...) não é de todo aconselhado [...]". Totalmente verdade. Entre outras dificuldades, pense que alguém que for usar ou dar manutenção no seu código pode não ter um teclado com cedilha (ç).

Comment: Claro @LuizVieira, basta ser de outro país para nem perceber bem aquilo hehe

Comment: no Linux (e provavelmente no Windows também) as portas menores que 1024 podem ser usadas como servidor apenas por processos privilegiados (root, administrator); assim, no exemplo do OP além de todos os erros havia a questão da porta 255 utilizada

Comment: exato @JoséX, correto